# SQL Server : I need the 2 last changes on articles

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of `Articles` from a hardware store WITH the history of the price changes in this articles

For example:

```
ARTICLE              | UPC | DATE    | PRICE
---------------------+-----+---------+---------
SCREWDRIVER DEWALT   | 001 |20190201 |  100
SCREWDRIVER DEWALT   | 001 |20181001 |   95
SCREWDRIVER DEWALT   | 001 |20170825 |   90
SCREWDRIVER DEWALT   | 001 |20160514 |   84
HAMMER DRILL B&D     | 002 |20190105 |  150
HAMMER DRILL B&D     | 002 |20180405 |  145   
HAMMER DRILL B&D     | 002 |20170505 |  130
HAMMER DRILL B&D     | 002 |20160605 |  120
```

I want to know only the 2 last changes in price for my ARTICLEs with the DATE in my SELECT (EXAMPLE: 100 and 95 and DATE 20190201,20181001 for the Screw and 150 and 150 with the date for the Hammer drill),  this idea is for 1000 articles

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Which database are you using ??

Comment: I use MS SQL for this

Answer (score 0):

We are going to create rankings by article and date. And then filter the top 2 rankings.

```
select * from 
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by articleNames order by date desc) as ranking from table 
) t1
where ranking <= 2
```